# How to open Interactive Brokers' TWS from within Python

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

A link to the latest version of TWS is [here](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/java/classes/latest.jnlp?counter=0.9639924327729598).

When I opened the link in Firefox while watching the 'network' traffic (Ctrl+Shift+Q) it seemed to show a GET request to

```
https://www.interactivebrokers.com/java/classes/latest.jnlp?counter=0.9639924327729598
```

(the counter is set to a random number). Yet, the following code returns a HTML web page; and not the 'latest.jnlp' file:

```
import requests
import random

url = 'https://www.interactivebrokers.com/java/classes/latest.jnlp?counter=' + str(random.random())
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
print r.content
```

How do I download the actual latest.jnlp file and save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions below illustrate two different ways to download the file:

```
import random
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.interactivebrokers.com/java/classes/latest.jnlp?counter=' + str(random.random())

def download_file_1(url):
    urllib.urlretrieve(url + ".jnlp", "latest.jnlp")

def download_file_2(url):
    jnlpfile = urllib2.urlopen(url + ".jnlp")
    output = open('test.jnlp','wb')
    output.write(jnlpfile.read())
    output.close()
```

Calling both these functions produces the same result: the file is simply downloaded and saved to the current working directory, with the names for the file specified as "latest.jnlp" and "test.jnlp". Since you didn't specify that it was necessary to use the requests library, I decided to use urllib and urllib2.

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: I had not realized that a .jnlp file looks similar to a HTML web page. It works now! Note to anyone browsing: I had a hard time getting the jnlp file to run in Windows 7 via Python. Apparently the UAC permissions don't allow it and there is no error message. As a workaround, I created a open.bat file (manually) containing the line `javaws latest.jnlp`.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got your problem solved and that the code works! Sometimes the solution is deceptively simple!